# Spring Boot REST controller only matches with trailing "/"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller such as:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class ServicesController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Something doStuff() {
        ...
    }
}
```

For my domain `www.bar.com`, the request mapping will be called when I visit `www.bar.com/foo/`, but not when I visit `www.bar.com/foo`. How can I make Spring trigger the same method for both `www.bar.com/foo/` and `www.bar.com/foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you take a look at your own code, you're saying that to access your `ServicesController`, you must go to `/foo`, and that to access your `doStuff`, you must go to `/`.

In short, you're saying that to call your `doStuff` method in your `ServicesController`, you must go to `/foo/`.

The right way in my opinion, to have a 'default' method for a class, you can do something like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class ServicesController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Something doStuff() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add another value like,

```
@RequestMapping(value={"","/"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Something doStuff() {
    ...
}
```

this will trigger for both the `www.bar.com/foo/` and `www.bar.com/foo`

Comment: Thanks Zionz, I could swear that I've tried this but I'll give it another go later this afternoon. I'm struggling to find anything in the documentation about this. I'll report back once I've given it a go, cheers.